# Python bootstrap times out downloading eggs

Tags: python, bootstrapping, buildout

```
$ python bootstrap.py
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
```

I am getting this error. What's odd is there is no problem getting to the file:

```
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
--2012-07-11 05:49:52--  http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Resolving pypi.python.org... 82.94.164.168
...
2012-07-11 05:49:58 (69.6 KB/s) - `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg' saved [333447/333447]
```

Also odd: there is an egg for different version of setuptools in ./eggs: setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg

The log looks like this:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Creating directory '/opt/mytardis/releases/0351b5a804156c3d060c7042ad558e87616dee6d/bin'.
Creating directory '/opt/mytardis/releases/0351b5a804156c3d060c7042ad558e87616dee6d/parts'.
Creating directory '/opt/mytardis/releases/0351b5a804156c3d060c7042ad558e87616dee6d/eggs'.
Creating directory '/opt/mytardis/releases/0351b5a804156c3d060c7042ad558e87616dee6d/develop-eggs'.
Getting distribution for 'setuptools'.
Got setuptools 0.6c12dev-r88846.
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Generated script '/opt/mytardis/releases/0351b5a804156c3d060c7042ad558e87616dee6d/bin/buildout'.
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Develop: '/opt/mytardis/releases/0351b5a804156c3d060c7042ad558e87616dee6d/.'
```

Any ideas? It's a Django app (not authored by me), which I'm trying to deploy through Vagrant and Chef. This step actually worked just a few hours ago (before I rebuilt the whole VM) so I'm a bit mystified what's changed. The buildout.cfg is [here](https://github.com/mytardis/mytardis/blob/master/buildout.cfg).

EDIT
A bit more info: it looks like the 'download error' is misleading, because the file actually does get downloaded to a temp directory (/tmp/tmpxxxx/). Running the buildout from the command line then immediately breaking shows this:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 172, in <module>
    ez['use_setuptools'](**setup_args)
  File "<string>", line 103, in use_setuptools
  File "<string>", line 99, in do_download
  File "/tmp/tmpkXNqcy/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpkXNqcy/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/extension.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpkXNqcy/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpkXNqcy/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/depends.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/version.py", line 63, in <module>
    class StrictVersion (Version):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/version.py", line 101, in StrictVersion
    re.VERBOSE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 243, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 510, in compile
    code = _code(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 495, in _code
    _compile(code, p.data, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 96, in _compile
    _compile(code, av[2], flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 107, in _compile
    _compile(code, av[1], flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 107, in _compile
    _compile(code, av[1], flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 88, in _compile
    _compile(code, av[2], flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 63, in _compile
    _compile_charset(av, flags, code, fixup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py", line 203, in _compile_charset
    if flags & SRE_FLAG_LOCALE:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than one page is checked for possible downloadable targets. If one of those is down or generates an error you get to see this warning. But it's only a warning, you'll get a proper error if things really go south.

The warning is issued to let you know setuptools *may* have selected a different version of a package than it would otherwise have; it collects a list of versions for the package from pypi and pages linked from there, and one of those pages timing out *could* mean a "better" version was not selected this time.

In other words: don't worry, status-by-design.

Comment: How bizarre! I'll need to look closer to see if stuff is actually missing. I was getting some actual failures, but not right now.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Nothing would be missing, per se; but setuptools cannot guarantee it got the latest or "best" versions (if there were version specifications) for you.